# knex js, select is working but not delete

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Trying out the query builder knex.js, http://knexjs.org/

```
exports.deleteProduct = function(inputs, callback) {
  //Working
  knex( "products" ).select().exec(function(err, resp) { console.log(resp) });

  //Not working
  knex( "products" ).del().where( "pr_id", 349).exec(function(err, resp) {          console.log(resp) });;    
}
```

The select statement works just fine. But not delete, also tried update. The response is 0. The record has not been deleted, have checked the db. I don't get any error if I run console.log(err) either.

Any ideas?

Comment: knexjs reports the number of row affected. That it returned `0` without an error means no row was affected. Try putting the `.where()`  on the select statement and see if you get any rows before you delete it.

Comment: Thx! Knex.js is much smoother then the sql string mess. Thx for the tip in my previous question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. I changed the where clause to an object instead.

```
/*
 DELETE /api/project/products/:pr_id HTTP/1.1
 */
exports.deleteProduct = function(inputs, callback) {
  var query = knex("products")
    .del()
    .where({
      pr_id:inputs.params.pr_id
  });

  query.exec( function(err){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    sendResponse(callback);
  })
}
```